# multiple welcome messages on multiple servers discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am new to this platform and also new with python. I wanted to create a Welcome Event, which says hello to new users. (messages shown in German)
Its working fine, however if i copy the event and just put other IDs in, it doesn't work how it should. I want to have multiple servers where my bot says hello to new members, and also multiple channels. i dont know how i can make that it says hello on more than just one server. i also dont know exactly how to read files. a method without files would be awesome. but i would be fine with files too, because i could try another command if i know how to work with files. here is my code with 2 servers. I guess you can see what i've tried. But it sends 2 messages in mainserver if i join mainserver and 1 message in mainserver if i join test server. so, it doesn't send any message in the testserver. anyone has an idea?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import Cogs
import main
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=test_prefix, case insensitive=True, intents=intents

    @bot.event
    async def on_member_join(member):
        #testserver
        guild = bot.get_guild(836268774465208380)
        channel = guild.get_channel(836659340391874600)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Herzlich Willkommen auf {guild.name}!', description=f'Heißen wir {member.mention} '
                                                                                          f'herzlich willkommen! Hab viel '
                                                                                          f'Spaß auf unserem Server!'
                                                                                          f' :smile:',
                              colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(146, 4, 30))
        embed.set_footer(text=f'Bot by {botowner}', icon_url=f'{avatarowner}')
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=guild.icon_url)
        embed.set_author(name=f'{member.name}', icon_url=f'{member.avatar_url}')
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
    
    @bot.event
    async def on_member_join(member):
        #my main server
        guild = bot.get_guild(572545560758976514)
        channel = guild.get_channel(572545561371213826)
        embed2 = discord.Embed(title=f'Herzlich Willkommen auf {guild.name}!', description=f'Heißen wir {member.mention} '
                                                                                          f'herzlich willkommen! Hab viel '
                                                                                          f'Spaß auf unserem Server!'
                                                                                          f' :smile:',
                              colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(146, 4, 30))
        embed2.set_footer(text=f'Bot by {botowner}', icon_url=f'{avatarowner}')
        embed2.set_thumbnail(url=guild.icon_url)
        embed2.set_author(name=f'{member.name}', icon_url=f'{member.avatar_url}')
        await channel.send(embed=embed2)

bot.run(test_token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are missing a `)` at the of the line you declare `bot`, and both of the `on_member_join` should be intended, I assume this might be a error from copying.
Second, you can only have each event once, so you would have to merge them in one.
Third, to your question. If you plan on realising your bot to the public sometime, you would have to use a file, so you can change the welcome channel in each guild from a command and don't have to redo this every time the bot restarts. To read json files, you use

```py
with open("your_json_file.json", "r") as json_file:
    json_dict = json.load(json_file) #this gets the contents of the json file and loads them to a dict object.
```

and to write to a json file:

```py
with open("your_json_file.json", "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(json_dict, json_file) #here you change to contents of json_file to json_dict
```

If you want guild owners to be able to change their welcome channel, you would have to implement a command to change it, which would first read and then write to a json file the new welcome channel. In this code I will be using a static dict, which is reset every time the bot restarts. You would also have to read your json file at the top of your `on_member_join` event.
Now for the code:
You declare `welcome_channels` at the top of your code like this:

```py
welcome_channels = {"First Guild id here":"First guild welcome channel id here", "Second Guild id here":"Second guild welcome channel id here", etc}
```

then, since you can only use one `on_member_join` event do it like this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    #maybe read json file here
    if member.guild.id in list(welcome_channels.keys):
        guild = member.guild
        channel = guild.get_channel(welcome_channels[member.guild.id])
        #The rest of your code can stay the same, except remove the second on_member_join
```

---

### References

- [Member.guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.guild)

Comment: thank you! i guess i am just too dumb for the json file, so i use the method with the welcome_channels and the id's from the channels and guilds. i just want to have 5 servers, with welcome and goodbye, and since goodbye is the same as welcome, i just can use it there too. thank you for your help!